# Visual Studio 2017 Team Foundation Error git bash "failed to acquire credentials"

Tags: git, visual-studio, atlassian-sourcetree

Enviroment:

- Windows 10 Home 1709
- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.5.3
- git version 2.16.1.windows.1

I get Team Foundation Error when "Team Explorer -> Sync"

Output (Source Control - Git) shows me

```
Opening repositories:
C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\project
Git failed with a fatal error.
failed to acquire credentials.
failed to acquire credentials.
failed to acquire credentials.
From ssh://developer.whereprojectis.com/projects/project
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      Version1.5 -> origin/Version1.5
 * [new branch]      gov        -> origin/gov
 * [new branch]      ver1.6.0   -> origin/ver1.6.0
```

> remote origin
>   ssh://git@developer.whereprojectis.com/projects/project.git

I can fetch, push, pull by git CMD with password.

However, Visual Studio unable to sync, fetch, push, pull.

How can I solve this?

---

I also can not push or pull by Source Tree.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
Error reading SSH_ASKPASS output for prompt: Password:
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can fetch, push, pull by git CMD with password.

That means your private SSH key has a passphrase.
Note: you could consider using one *without* passphrase to avoid the ssh agent setup.

Regarding SourceTree, check what git it is using in the settings (native or system): try the system one.
And check `Tools > Options > General > SSH Client Configuration`: it should use OpenSSH.

Comment: I change SourceTree's SSH Client Configuration to **OpenSSH**. However it fails becuase _The OpenSSH agent is running but the server still rejected your connection._ I guess server manager could set SSH Key... But still mystery that I can use password in git CMD.

Comment: @ibocon That is why I suggested not using a passphrase: you would need to use a ppk Putty SSH key instead: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Using-SourceTree-For-Windows-With-SSH-Keys/qaq-p/254386

Answer (score 0):

In my case the answer was rather simple: visual studio never ever asked me for a password because the ssh client didn't yet know the server's hostkey/fingerprint.
In this case when you push/pull the first time via ssh you get the corresponding message and are promptet to state wether you want to accept the key or not.
Unfortunately VisualStudio 2019 doesn't care abot it and then get's stuck because git cancels the request because of not accepting the servert host key.

Doing one first pull on the first repo on that git server on command prompt and manually acctepting the key there solved it for me. Works fine since then.